# Update an int value using PostgreSQL and C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

```
Update "Batery" Set "Stock" = 10 + "Stock"  Where "idBatery" = 1
```

I did execute this query in the Postgres and it worked. How do I do the query using **C#**.

I did try this:

```
"Update \"Batery\" Set \"Stock\" = " + tbAddStock.Text +"+ \"Stock\"  Where \"idBatery\" = "+ tbIdBatery.Text
```

uning command syntax:

```
"Update \"Batery\" Set \"Stock\" = (:stock) + \"Stock\"  Where \"idBatery\" = (:idbatery)"
```

And i get an error that say: "Syntax error in or close to <<"Stock">>", in the first case.
In the cmd case i get "Cant convert an 'System.String[]' object to 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: I cheked that im sending Integer as DataType in the parameter.

Comment: *and nothing* is not a valid Postgres or C# error message.

Comment: Are you behind a transaction, maybe it's not being committed?

Comment: the textfield's has the data, when cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is executed, i get that error.

Comment: ive previously added stuff in the database, and get stuff.. but this is my first update and i dont know how to do it.

Comment: I found the answer, cant publish it yet.. 7hours ^^

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code to illustrate using Npgsql (C# API for PostgreSQL)

1) Create a Command
2) Add parameters to the Command
3) Add values for each parameter to the command
4) Execute as a 'non query' (not expecting SQL rows returned)
5) catch your database errors

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand( "update battery set stock = :stock where id = :id;", connection);
try
{
 command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("stock", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
 command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
 command.Parameters[0].Value = stock;
 command.Parameters[1].Value = id;

 command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.
}
catch( NpgsqlException e )
{
....
}
```